# Открыть фото категории yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Нужно, чтобы по нажатию на ссылку в категории фото - формировалась страничка  c результатами именной той категории по переданному параметру $id

Есть модуль и по 2 модели котроллера
Одна модель - categories , вторая - album

В контроллере создал екшин

```
public function actionAlbum()
    {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);

    }
```

По нажатию рендерится страничка categories/album.
И вот нужно чтобы выводило именно то что нужно.
Понимаю что должен был запрос что-то типо

```
 public function getContent()
{
    $id = 6; //тестовое значение к примеру
   return $contents = Content::find()
        ->select('Content.*')
        ->innerJoin('category', '`category`.`category_id` = `content`.`id`')
        ->where(['content.id' == $id])
        ->all();
    return ArrayHelper::map($contents, 'id', 'name');

}
```

Но не понимаю куда прописывать, или это в контроллера должно быть или в модели. И как потом вызвать во вью то, что возвращает метод getContent().
Кто что думает??

Comment: очень рекомендую прочесть всё что тут есть: http://guide.yii2.org-info.by/guide-ru-README.html

Потому что вместо того, чтобы использовать обычные методы в Yii2, вы пытаетесь написать своё и какое-то кривое. Вот тут вы найдёте то, что нужно в вашем случае: http://guide.yii2.org-info.by/guide-ru-structure-controllers.html

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю